# Bootable Windows USB UEFI and GPT table

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb, partitioning

I have an Windows 10 iso
I have an SD card with an SD card reader (basically a slow pen drive)

I have created an GPT partition table on the pen drive* with one partition of full space.I have copied iso files by using disk image mounter in Garuda linux

The problem is that the UEFI isn't showing the usb and thus it's not booting and also legacy won't work due to it being gpt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe that the SD card must be formatted as MBR.

Comment: Seems like you have created an NFTS partition but your Firmware (UEFI) can only boot from FAT32 Partition may be?

Comment: Do you have ideological objections regarding the usage of the official Media Creator tool or Rufus, or Ventoy? If not then use either.